# Is there a faster way to run test-app repeatedly in Eclipse STS?

Tags: eclipse, grails, junit

Running test-app under Eclipse STS is slow for me because it has to start up the Grails app stack each time.  On the command line I can run Grails interactively then run "test-app -functional" and it's very quick.  Is there a way to do this under STS and get the pretty JUnit  bars?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but it might help.

Try the grails [AutoTest](http://grails.org/blog/view/willy/AutoTest+plugin+released) plugin. The author created a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qLuDlJqFwY) to demo it.

Comment: Nice!  That is helpful to know.  Thanks for that tip!